# Apache config-based redirect - not preserving GET vars in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Good afternoon all,

I'm redirecting a site (example.net) to another (example.org) for both HTTP and HTTPS.  This works as expected:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.net
        ServerAlias www.example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.org
        Redirect permanent / https://example.org/?r=xxx
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.net
        ServerAlias www.example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.org
        Redirect permanent / https://example.org/?r=xxx
    </VirtualHost>
```

However, site example.org is not receiving the r=xxx parameter.  $_SERVER/$_GET/$_REQUEST do not contain the R variable.

I cannot use .htaccess unfortunately, hence the Apache config redirect.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: what is the destination URL? did you clean your cache before test? permanent redirect always cached by browser

Comment: Thanks Ben, you are correct.  Used Chrome incognito mode and bingo...